# how to test my simplesamlphp SP service with an adfs IDP server online?

Tags: php, authentication, single-sign-on, adfs, simplesamlphp

I have installed simplesapl as a SP in my localhost, Now I want to test my this service with any adfs as an idp. Is there any way to check this online for free?. I do not have any adfs installed locally.

Answer (score 1):

ADFS is not a free product. You have to have a license for Windows Server.

If you have a MSDN account, you could run up a server as an Azure VM.

I don't know of any publicly available ADFS.

There are a number of publicly available IDP e.g. [SSO Circle](http://www.ssocircle.com/en/).

They all implement the same protocols so that would be a good first step.